# Get substring from dynamic data c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am getting continuously changing data on my console using DataReceivedEventArgs event. Now I have to extract only the `int` value of Total. for that I am using string function `Substring()`

I am using like below:

```
e.Data.Substring(7, e.Data.IndexOf("f"));
```

because no of total and fps are kept changing when it increase I am start losing the digit.

Please help to make it dynamic so whatever value lie between total and fps, I want to get it

Below is the data sample
`Total= 1082 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:36.33`

Comment: See regex......

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UB14pC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, ranging from easy to more difficult, the easiest it to use `IndexOf("Total=")` and `IndexOf("fps")`, like

```
Console.WriteLine(e.Data.Substring(e.Data.IndexOf("Total="), e.Data.IndexOf("fps")));
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c2xNN9)

But that will break if the order of `Total`, `fps`, etc ever changes, so instead you can use RegEx, like

```cs
var input = "Total= 1082 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:36.33";
var regexString = @"Total=(\s)*[0-9]+";
var regex = new Regex(regexString);
var match = regex.Match(input);
Console.WriteLine(match);
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fuRZh3)

You could also build a parser and parse the data into a object, but that's out of scope for this answer.

---

P.S if you can change the source code of what's generating this event and data, you may want to think about not passing strings betweens parts of your application and instead pass objects and format those for console (or any other) presentation

Comment: it is working but it also adding ```total= ``` I don't want to get this. I only need digits